# Why does pymc.MAP not always return the same value

Tags: pymc

I am running pymc2 to fit a straight line through my data. The code is shown below (modified from examples I found online). When I call the MAP function multiple times, I get different answers, even though I start with the exact same model. I thought the optimization method, fmin_powell, starts at the supplied `value` for each parameter. As far as I know, fmin_powell has no random component, so it should always end at the same optimum, yet it doesn't. Why do I keep getting different results?

```
import numpy as np
import pymc

# observed data
n = 21
a = 6
b = 2
sigma = 2
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
np.random.seed(1)
y_obs = a * x + b + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)

def model():
    # define priors
    a = pymc.Normal('a', mu=0, tau=1  /10 ** 2, value=5)
    b = pymc.Normal('b', mu=0, tau=1 / 10 ** 2, value=1)
    tau = pymc.Gamma('tau', alpha=0.1, beta=0.1, value=1)

    # define likelihood
    @pymc.deterministic
    def mu(a=a, b=b, x=x):
        return a * x + b

    y = pymc.Normal('y', mu=mu, tau=tau, value=y_obs, observed=True)
    return locals()

ml = model()  # dictionary of all locals
mcmc = pymc.Model(ml)  # MCMC object
mapmcmc = pymc.MAP(mcmc)
mapmcmc.fit(method='fmin_powell')
print(mcmc.a.value, mcmc.b.value, mcmc.tau.value)

ml = model()  # dictionary of all locals
mcmc = pymc.Model(ml)  # MCMC object
mapmcmc = pymc.MAP(mcmc)
mapmcmc.fit(method='fmin_powell')
print(mcmc.a.value, mcmc.b.value, mcmc.tau.value)

ml = model()  # dictionary of all locals
mcmc = pymc.Model(ml)  # MCMC object
mapmcmc = pymc.MAP(mcmc)
mapmcmc.fit(method='fmin_powell')
print(mcmc.a.value, mcmc.b.value, mcmc.tau.value)
```

Comment: do you know if using directly the minimizations proposed by the 'scipy' module without pymc shows the same feature ?